# Java Swing GridLayout not looking like I expect it to

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have a GUI that is a grid layout with 6 rows and 4 columns, the order should go:
Label - RadioButton - RadioButton - ComboBox

This is successful for the first row. However each row afterwards is messed up. Please refer to the image of the GUI.

Please disregard the commented code as I am going to be setting the visibility later once I complete the GUI layout. Thanks.

[image: GUI]

```
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Zoho DNC List Updater");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(height, width);

        // creating menu bar
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        // mb.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JMenu m1 = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu m2 = new JMenu("Help");
        mb.add(m1);
        mb.add(m2);

        JMenuItem contact = new JMenuItem("Contact Us");
        JMenuItem help = new JMenuItem("Help");
        JMenuItem openFile = new JMenuItem("Open File");
        JMenuItem saveFile = new JMenuItem("Save File");
        JMenuItem newWindow = new JMenuItem("New window");

        m2.add(contact);
        m2.add(help);
        m1.add(openFile);
        m1.add(saveFile);
        m1.add(newWindow);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // the panel is not visible in output
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Update Records");
        // JTextField tf = new JTextField(10); // accepts upto 10 characters
        JButton send = new JButton("Update");
        JButton reset = new JButton("Quit");
        panel.add(label); // Components Added using Flow Layout
        // panel.add(tf);
        panel.add(send);
        panel.add(reset);

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 4));

        JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Yes");
        JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("No");
        JLabel custom = new JLabel("Customize Call Report?");
        ButtonGroup btnGrp = new ButtonGroup();
        radio1.setBounds(120, 30, 120, 50);
        radio2.setBounds(120, 30, 120, 50);
        custom.setBounds(120, 30, 120, 50);
        btnGrp.add(radio1);
        btnGrp.add(radio2);

        JComboBox campsList = new JComboBox(camps);
        campsList.setSelectedIndex(5);
        campsList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r){
                JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)r.getSource();
                String campName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
                
             }
        });
        JComboBox inboundsList = new JComboBox(inbounds);
        inboundsList.setSelectedIndex(5);
        inboundsList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r){
                JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)r.getSource();
                String campName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
                
             }
        });
        JComboBox statList = new JComboBox(stat);
        statList.setSelectedIndex(5);
        statList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r){
                JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)r.getSource();
                String campName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
                
             }
        });

    JComboBox groupList = new JComboBox(groups);
    groupList.setSelectedIndex(5);
    groupList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r){
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)r.getSource();
            String campName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            
         }
    });
    
    JComboBox lisList = new JComboBox(lis);
    lisList.setSelectedIndex(5);
    lisList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r){
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)r.getSource();
            String campName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            
         }
    });

        ButtonGroup btnGrp1 = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton campaignY = new JRadioButton("Yes");
        JRadioButton campaignN = new JRadioButton("No");
        JLabel campaign = new JLabel("Select all campaigns?");
        campaignY.setBounds(120, 30, 120, 50);
        campaignN.setBounds(120, 30, 120, 50);
        btnGrp1.add(campaignY);
        btnGrp1.add(campaignN);

        ButtonGroup btnGrp2 = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton inboundY = new JRadioButton("Yes");
        JRadioButton inboundN = new JRadioButton("No");
        JLabel inbound = new JLabel("Select all inbound groups?");
        btnGrp2.add(inboundY);
        btnGrp2.add(inboundN);

        ButtonGroup btnGrp3 = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton statusY = new JRadioButton("Yes");
        JRadioButton statusN = new JRadioButton("No");
        JLabel status = new JLabel("Select all call statuses?");
        btnGrp3.add(statusY);
        btnGrp3.add(statusN);
        statusY.setBounds(120, 30, 120, 50);
        statusN.setBounds(120, 30, 120, 50);

        ButtonGroup btnGrp4 = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton userGroupY = new JRadioButton("Yes");
        JRadioButton userGroupN = new JRadioButton("No");
        JLabel userGroup = new JLabel("Select all user groups?");
        btnGrp4.add(userGroupY);
        btnGrp4.add(userGroupN);

        userGroupY.setBounds(120, 30, 120, 50);
        userGroupN.setBounds(120, 30, 120, 50);

        ButtonGroup btnGrp5 = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton listsY = new JRadioButton("Yes");
        JRadioButton listsN = new JRadioButton("No");
        JLabel lists = new JLabel("Select all lists?");
        btnGrp5.add(listsY);
        btnGrp5.add(listsN);

        panel2.add(custom);
        panel2.add(radio1);
        panel2.add(radio2);
        campsList.setVisible(true);
        panel2.add(campsList);

        panel2.add(campaign);
        panel2.add(campaignY);
        panel2.add(campaignN);
        inboundsList.setVisible(true);
        panel2.add(inboundsList);
      //  campaign.setVisible(false);
      //  campaignY.setVisible(false);
      //  campaignN.setVisible(false);

        panel2.add(status);
        panel2.add(statusY);
        panel2.add(statusN);
        panel2.add(statList);
       // status.setVisible(false);
       // statusY.setVisible(false);
       // statusN.setVisible(false);

        panel2.add(inbound);
        panel2.add(inboundY);
        panel2.add(inboundN);
        panel2.add(inboundsList);
      //  inbound.setVisible(false);
     //   inboundN.setVisible(false);
     //   inboundY.setVisible(false);

        panel2.add(userGroup);
        panel2.add(userGroupY);
        panel2.add(userGroupN);
        panel2.add(groupList);
       // userGroup.setVisible(false);
      //  userGroupN.setVisible(false);
      //  userGroupY.setVisible(false);

        panel2.add(lists);
        panel2.add(listsY);
        panel2.add(listsN);
        panel2.add(lisList);
      //  lists.setVisible(false);
     //   listsN.setVisible(false);
     //   listsY.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

So, there are two issues.

First, when both the column and row properties are specified, the column value is ignore, as you can find in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)

> When both the number of rows and the number of columns have been set to non-zero values, either by a constructor or by the setRows and setColumns methods, the number of columns specified is ignored. Instead, the number of columns is determined from the specified number of rows and the total number of components in the layout.

So, in your case, I changed it to `JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4));`

Second, an instance component may only reside in a single parent, once.

```
    panel2.add(custom);
    panel2.add(radio1);
    panel2.add(radio2);
    panel2.add(campsList);
    
    panel2.add(campaign);
    panel2.add(campaignY);
    panel2.add(campaignN);
    panel2.add(inboundsList);

    //...

    panel2.add(inbound);
    panel2.add(inboundY);
    panel2.add(inboundN);
    panel2.add(inboundsList);
```

You're adding `inboundsList` twice, this has the effect of first removing it from the container and then re-adding it at the new position.

You will need to create a new instance of the of the `JComoboBox` with the same data model